# opening chrome tab from bash function multicommand alias

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have a bash function I want to use to open all projects:

```
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1; workon $1; port $2 ; (sleep 3) && (google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2/$3 &) ;}
```

The goal is to pass the project name, port, and an optional url path as $3 if needed, My runproject works up till opening the chrome page, which never opens. This series works though:

```
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1; workon $1; port $2 ;} 

alias runautohelper='(runproject autohelper 8009 &) && (sleep 3) && (google-chrome 127.0.0.1:8009/bitbucket/create-repo &)'
alias runjavascript='(runproject javascript-practice 8111 &) && (sleep 3) && (google-chrome 127.0.0.1:8111/ &)'
```

this is now polluting my bash_profile with these long commands. How can I fix this runproject to work taking the 3 args I want it to? Thank you

set -x shows it failing right after starting the django runserver:

```
cchilders:~$ runproject scriptamajig 8002
+ runproject scriptamajig 8002
+ cd /home/cchilders/projects/scriptamajig
+ workon scriptamajig
+ all sortsa messy venv setup stuff ending in "rm -f /tmp/virtualenvwrapper-post_activate-hook-5dpzsx8fRm"
+ return 0
+ return 0
+ port 8002
+ fuser -k 8002/tcp
8002/tcp:             8524
+ python manage.py runserver 8002
Performing system checks...
```

`fuser -k 8002/tcp` is exactly what `port 8002` does. I don't know why `set -x` doesn't show it sleeping, but even removing the sleep statement it fails similarly. From googling results in shellcheck.net I feel it's the way google-chrome function interprets strings (the `127.0.0.1:$2/$3` part), which is normally the problem in bash

fail (runs server but doesn't open chrome):

```
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome "127.0.0.1:$2/" ;} 
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:"$2"/ ;} 
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 ; sleep 3 ; "google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2"/ ;} 
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 ; sleep 3 ; "google-chrome 127.0.0.1:"$2/ ;} 
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome "127.0.0.1:"$2 ;}
```

testing the chrome aspect isolated with

```
chromeit() { google-chrome $1 ;}
```

yields correct result twice:

```
cchilders:~/projects/scriptamajig [master]$ chromeit "127.0.0.1:8000"
Created new window in existing browser session.
cchilders:~/projects/scriptamajig [master]$ chromeit 127.0.0.1:8000
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

testing

```
chromeitport() { google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$1 ;}
```

proves syntax of chrome command works, the issue is in chaining the commands in `runproject`:

```
cchilders:~/projects/scriptamajig [master]$ chromeitport 8002
Created new window in existing browser session.
cchilders:~/projects/scriptamajig [master]$ [08/Apr/2016 17:38:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14081
[08/Apr/2016 17:38:43] "GET /media/css/codemirror.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Apr/2016 17:38:43] "GET /media/js/codemirror/codemirror-modes.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/Apr/2016 17:38:43] "GET /media/js/codemirror/codemirror.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
...all 200 or 3xx...
```

I've determined `port $2` running in the foreground is the issue, but attempting

```
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 & ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2 ;}
```

causes

```
cchilders:~/projects/scriptamajig [master]$ src
bash: /home/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 134: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: /home/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 134: `runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 & ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2 ;} '
```

Is there a way to run multiple things in the background in a chained bash function? Thank you

Comment: I don't have an env with `google-chrome` available from cmd line, but lots of odd(ish) stuff here. why use `&&` before `sleep`. Do you expect it to fail, where as `workon $1; port $2;` will never fail and you can assume everything is alright? Also I don't see the need for `( cmd )` (sub-processes in parens), when just `sleep` and `g-chrome` should be fine without that. First thing to try is just remove the `( ...)` around `google-chrome`. Good luck!

Comment: Does `google-chrome` get executed with your attempted function? Does it error? Does it return? Does it hang? What does `set -x` say is run exactly?

Comment: set -x is so beautiful mr. reisner, even if I can't fix this bash function you just saved me hours of my life ;)

Comment: Good show improving your Q.! Another general comment is to (almost) always surround variable references in dbl-quotes. Try `runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/"$1" ; workon "$1" ; port "$2" & ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:"$2" ; }` (note I've also added another space after the last `;` char.) Also more likely to fix your error by changing to `..; port "$2" & sleep 3 ; ...` I think the `&` counts as a command separator, and so the `;` would be parsed as "extra, an unneeded". (not precise terminology ;-). Try switching to putting each command on a separate line. You'll get better err msgs.